# Initialize an object using a block instead of constructor arguments

Tags: ruby, object

I have a class with a constructor that takes two parameters and sets the fields to those values. I want to also be able to initialize objects from this class by setting fields explicitly inside of a block passed to the constructor.

The constructor:

```
class Grammar
    attr_reader :rules, :start, ...
    def initialize(rules, start)
        @rules = rules
        @start = start
        ...
    end
end
```

The parameters passed to the constructor involve creating several objects that are only used as intermediate building blocks for the parameters `rules` and `start` and it would make sense to limit the existence of these objects to the block passed to the constructor. In this block I would expect to first build the intermediate objects and then directly set the fields of the new object.

I want to be able to instantiate `Grammar` like so:

```
grammar = Grammar.new { |g|
    ...
    # build rules and start
    ...
    g.start = start
    g.rules = rules
}
```

How should I modify the constructor to allow both methods of initialisation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually really easy to add this functionality to most classes provided they already have `attr_writer` and/or `attr_accessor` in place:

```
class Grammar
  attr_accessor :rules, :start, ...

  def initialize(rules, start)
    @rules = rules
    @start = start
    ...

    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

Where you can now do exactly what you wanted. The `yield self` part will supply the object being initialized to the block, and `block_given?` is only `true` if you've supplied a block to the `new` call. You'll want to run this after setting all your defaults.

Comment: I think they would need `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor` here.

Comment: So do I have to change the access to these variables in order to be able to set them from within a block? I want to leave this data structure immutable.

Comment: You could do it with a short-term proxy object but that's a whole other solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [Object#Tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) which is built-in to Ruby — yields self to the block, and then returns self.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name 
end

person = Person.new.tap do |p|
  p.name = "Jan"
end

puts person.name # hi
```

Comment: Clever, but fairly unconventional, so best reserved for cases where a first-class `yield` in the `initializer` is not an option, like using a third-party library.